# How to save Json in the django database from Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, sqlite

I will generate a json and save it in a string variable, and I need to save the whole json in my database.

I have a view

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'votes/dashboard.html'
```

in this template, I have javascript, and in this javascript I'm generating Json and saving it in a js variable, and I want to put the json in the variable into the DB.

As I'm gonna create a object for the jsons, I'll change templateview to CreateView as It's gonna save.

But how is this json going to become available for the view to be saved ?

Comment: `model = Model(json_field=json_data); model.save()`

Comment: @hadi but how do I make javascript save it in the db ?

Comment: You need to post the json data to a django view, and then use a JsonField to store de data.

Comment: no , send data via ajax and store it in database

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: I will edit my post to provide more information, I'm a bit confused about the answers,

Comment: @hadi I never used Ajax before, Could you please show me how I will use it to save the data ?, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

**brief instruction**

using jquery ajax:

```
$.post( "/your/url/for/store/json/data", { jsonField: jsonData } );
```

in your view:

```
def save_json_data(request):
    ...
    data = request.POST.get("jsonField", "")
    model = YourModel(json_field=data)
    model.save()
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help, Clear up something, this url in $.post, is the url referring to the def save json data ?